# Drools Windowing is Executing other rules after when the window time is over

Tags: drools, kie, drools-fusion, drools-flow

I am using Drool Fusion to execute windowing rules. The following is my Test class:

```
public class Test {
    int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public Test(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

When i am trying to execute the following rule i am getting unexpected result:

```
declare Test
@role(event)
@timestamp(time)
@expires(10m)
end


rule "Sliding window test1"
agenda-group "g0"
when
    $number: Number() from accumulate(Test($t:count <10) over window:time(10s) , average($t))
then
   System.out.println("Test Rule 1 " + $number );
end

rule "Sliding window test2"
agenda-group "g0"
when
    $number: Number() from accumulate(Test($t:count >10 ) over window:time(10s) , average($t))
then
   System.out.println("Test Rule 2 " + $number );
end
```

> Response : After the end of window rule i.e `10 seconds` both the rules is getting fired.

My Implementer is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("window-session");
        SessionPseudoClock clock = kieSession.getSessionClock();
        long curr = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true) {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
                Test test = new Test(i);
                kieSession.insert(test);
                kieSession.getAgenda().getAgendaGroup("g0").setFocus();
                clock.advanceTime(time - clock.getCurrentTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                kieSession.fireAllRules();
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - curr);
                Thread.sleep(10); //historical event test
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting unexpected output i.e after 10 seconds both the rules is firing after 1 second it is repeating the same. This behaviour is only happening when i am using `Pseudo clock`.
Kindly Help